# How to connect with Socket.io? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I have read the [latest documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) of **Socket.io** for Swift. And there is an example of a new connection:

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

So I have created a class **SocketIOManager**, like this:

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "myurl.com:443"))
    static let socket = manager.defaultSocket

    class func connectSocket(){
        socket.connect()
    }

    class func reciveMessage(){    
            socket.on("new-message-mob") { (dataArray, ack) in
                print(dataArray.count)
            }
    }
}
```

And then I just invoke the method **SocketIOManager.connectSocket()** in my ViewController. But the server produce the error. I don't develop the server side. I just need to know - did I create connection properly? How do you connect to socket through Socket.io these days?

P.S Server error - jwt must be provided (it seems like no token, but there is).

**UPDATE (with dummy values):**

I'm passing token like this:

```
static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://myurl:443?token=\(token)")!)
static let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

Comment: > `it seems like no token, but there is`. But your code doesn't have token. Are you sure that you pass the token?

Comment: I pass a token like this: static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://myurl.com:443?token=\(token)")!). But I'm not sure how to pass URL parameters.

Comment: check again how you put token. Can we see an example with dummy values?

Comment: update my post with token example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you set the `token` in wrong place. According to the [issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/911), `token` should be set as header parameter in configuration:

```
manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
    arrayLiteral: .compress, .connectParams(["Authorization": token])
)
```

Try to manage your `token` this way.

Comment: Yes, it's solved my issue. But there are more settings we have to add to run this bad boy. See my answer below if someone faced the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

So, to solve this issue we have to do a couple of actions:

1. Add a **.connectParams(["token": token])** for manager.config - in my
   case I have to use "token" key as URL parameter.
2. Add a **.secure(true)**
   parameter for manager.config.
3. Add an **"App Transport Security
   Settings"** key in info.plist (Dictionary type)  and sub key "Allow
   Arbitrary Loads" (boolean type) with YES value.

**CODE:**

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://yoururl.com:443")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    static let socket = manager.defaultSocket


    class func connectSocket(){
        self.manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
            arrayLiteral: .connectParams(["token": token], .secure(true)
        )
        socket.connect()
    }

    class func disconnectSocket(){
        socket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know this?

Comment: this not works, please update your answer thanks.