# How to connect Socket in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I want to connect my app to the socket here is the code :-

```
  import UIKit
  import SocketIO

 class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "myURL")!)
static let socket = manager.defaultSocket


class func connectSocket() {
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.getAccessToken()

    self.manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
        arrayLiteral: .connectParams(["token": token]), .secure(true) // problem is here in passing token value
        )
        socket.connect()
}

class func receiveMsg() {
    socket.on("new message here") { (dataArray, ack) in

        print(dataArray.count)

    }
}
}
```

I created a new class SocketIOManager.swift and I invoke my function in view controller

```
  SocketIOManager.connectSocket()
```

and I am not using the localhost url but still my app is not connected to the socket I think I followed this  [How to connect with Socket.io? Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491357/how-to-connect-with-socket-io-swift-4)[image] and I also add App Transport Security in info.plist. Any help? The problem is when I am passing the token value it gives me error otherwise it is working properly. Should I need to pass token when using socket?

Comment: It is clear that there is a problem with the url. Try the connection through http://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/  message and tell me if the connection was successful or not .

Comment: It is showing connected

Comment: socket deploy localhost or on server ?

Comment: I am using server url

Comment: If the problem is not resolved please open discussion, I will send you Socket url for testing

Comment: okay I am doing this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169677/discussion-between-viper-and-a-masri).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a shared property in your `SocketIOManager` class like this:

```
static let shared = SocketIOManager()
```

and then create `init()` like this:

```
    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    // defaultNamespaceSocket and swiftSocket both share a single connection to the server
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

    override init() {
        super.init()

        socket = manager.defaultSocket
        }
```

and finally write your methods like this:

```
func connectSocket() {
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.getAccessToken()

    self.manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
        arrayLiteral: .connectParams(["token": token]), .secure(true)
        )
        socket.connect()
}

func receiveMsg() {
    socket.on("new message here") { (dataArray, ack) in

        print(dataArray.count)

    }
}
```

and call your method like this:

```
SocketIOManager.shared.connectSocket()
```

The point is that you should make a strong reference to manager property in your viewController and `static let shared = SocketIOManager()` you do this for you!

Comment: ERROR SocketEngine: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. I am getting this error sir

Comment: I think this is AppTransport security error. Isn't it?
Did you set it up correctly?

Comment: its not I did what app transport needs

Comment: So connect to your server manager and check if there is some additional configuration for connecting to server

Comment: it is correct but I want to know one thing is it necessary to pass token

Comment: Thanks man. ".connectParams(["token": token]" saved my life!:)

Comment: Hi @SeyedSamadGholamzadeh please update your answer its to old i need new version of socket io connection with token so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is your URL secured under HTTPS?
If it is not, that could be the problem, due to App Transport Security restrictions.

See [Info Plist Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

See also this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

If that's not the problem. I'd suggest to check if your Socket version on both sides, server and client, are the same. Recently I had a problem because of that.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

try this Example:

```
 let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: 
 "http://xxxxxxxxx.com")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
 var socket = manager.defaultSocket

socket.connect()
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
        self.gotConnection()
       }
    }

 func gotConnection(){

 socket.on("new message here") { (dataArray, ack) in

    print(dataArray.count)

     }
   }
```

Comment: what changes you made??

Comment: my code is working but when I am passing the token value its not working

Comment: socket.on(client: SocketEngineClient, url: URL, options: [String : 
     Any]?) in
            
           }
        }

Comment: pass url and options in the place send token try it this after connect socket to server