# Socket.io for swift4 ios

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am in trouble how to implement websocket function to my swift code.

I have completed a server implementation and another javascript client.
They are working well.
So, I believe websocket server is not wrong.

But if I write the code in swift, it don't work. No error happen and no message is shown on the console.

Here is my swift code.

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var bottomView: ChatRoomInputView!

    var chats: [ChatEntity] = []

    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        // Initialize WebSocket
        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://example.com:8081")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
        socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }

        socket.on("server_to_client") {[weak self] data, ack in
            print ("get Massage!!!")
        }

        socket.connect()

        socket.emit("join_room", with: [getRegistrationId()])
        socket.emit("client_to_server", with: ["ack_client"])

        setupUI()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return bottomView
    }

    func setupUI() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 113/255, green: 148/255, blue: 194/255, alpha: 1)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 113/255, green: 148/255, blue: 194/255, alpha: 1)

        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10000
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourChatViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourChat")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyChatViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyChat")

        self.bottomView = ChatRoomInputView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60))
        bottomView.chatTextField.delegate = self
        bottomView.textSendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.chatTextSendButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.chats.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let chat = self.chats[indexPath.row]
        if chat.isMyChat() {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyChat") as! MyChatViewCell
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
            // Todo: isRead
            cell.updateCell(text: chat.text, time: chat.time, isRead: true)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourChat") as! YourChatViewCell
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.updateCell(text: chat.text, time: chat.time, pic: RemoshinData.getDoctorPic())
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.inputFieldBorderBottom(color: Utils.getColor(),
                                     x: textField.center.x,
                                     y: textField.center.y,
                                     w: textField.frame.size.width,
                                     h: textField.frame.size.height)
        bottomView.chatTextField = textField
        return true
    }
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.inputFieldBorderBottom(color: UIColor.lightGray,
                                     x: textField.center.x,
                                     y: textField.center.y,
                                     w: textField.frame.size.width,
                                     h: textField.frame.size.height)
        return true
    }


    @objc func chatTextSendButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let chatText = bottomView.chatTextField.text!

        if (chatText != "") {
            let _mainViewController = MainViewController()
            let jsonData = _mainViewController.sendChatText(_registration_id: getRegistrationId(), _chat_text: chatText)

            if(jsonData["status"].string! == "success") {
                socket.emit("client_to_server", with: ["update_chat"])

                let chat = ChatEntity(text: jsonData["chat_text"].string!, time: "", userType: .I)
                chats.append(chat)
                tableView.reloadData()

                bottomView.chatTextField.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see "socket connected" message on my console when the app run. I think the socket is something wrong. But I have no idea what is wrong because no error message found. And I doubt if I need some setting in my info.plist. But, I don't make sense how to write.

Please give me some advice?

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001818/how-to-connect-socket-in-swift-4 just don't pass token in your case

Comment: There is no line on the console. No message is displayed.

Comment: are you review my code @KazzzStudio? you just need to set your manager object in global scope

Comment: Yes, I did. I can get the message when I tried to connect to my websocket server..

Comment: Please note that socket.io is not the same as WebSockets (although socket.io might use WebSockets internally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift%20SocketManager%20object%20create%20in%20global%20scope)

```
var manager:SocketManager!

var socketIOClient: SocketIOClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ConnectToSocket()
}

func ConnectToSocket() {

    manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "your url")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    socketIOClient = manager.defaultSocket

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print(data)
        print("socket connected")
    }

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .error) { (data, eck) in
        print(data)
        print("socket error")
    }

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, eck) in
        print(data)
        print("socket disconnect")
    }

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: SocketClientEvent.reconnect) { (data, eck) in
        print(data)
        print("socket reconnect")
    }

    socketIOClient.connect()
}
```

**Update**

In your case: **SocketManager: Manager is being released**

Sockets created through the manager are retained by the manager. So at the very least, a single strong reference to the manager must be maintained to keep sockets alive.

> ["Got unknown error from server Welcome to socket.io."]

1. Check socket.io version on both server and client side, mismatch of both may be cause of this error
2. Add an "App Transport Security Settings" key in info.plist (Dictionary type) and sub key "Allow Arbitrary Loads" (boolean type) with YES value.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I tried your code And I got the following error message. ["Got unknown error from server Welcome to socket.io."]
socket error. I have no idea what is wrong because another client(javascript) connect correctly.