# Socket after some time randomly changing status in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

First time socket connecting successfully and working well but after sometime randomly its changing their behavior due to this my message sent is failed.

Can anyone pls help me in this context, thanks.

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket reconnect

socket reconnect

socket reconnect

socket reconnect

socket reconnectAttempt

socket reconnectAttempt

socket reconnectAttempt

socket reconnectAttempt

socket statusChange

socket connecting

socket statusChange

socket connecting

socket statusChange

socket connecting

socket statusChange

socket connecting

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

socket statusChange

socket not connected

Comment: its may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062606/5461400

Comment: My code is for older version Instead of this
 manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "your url")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    socketIOClient = manager.defaultSocket

I have used this>
 var socket : SocketIOClient =  SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: baseURL3)! as URL)